# Creating an aggregate metrics from JSON logs in apache spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting started with apache spark.
I have a requirement to convert a json log to a flattened metrics, can be considered as a simple csv as well.

For eg.

```
  "orderId":1,
  "orderData": {
  "customerId": 123,
  "orders": [
    {
      "itemCount": 2,
      "items": [
        {
          "quantity": 1,
          "price": 315
        },
        {
          "quantity": 2,
          "price": 300
        },

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This can be considered as a single json log, I want to convert this into,

```
orderId,customerId,totalValue,units
  1    ,   123    ,   915    ,  3
```

I was going through sparkSQL documentation and can use it to get hold of individual values like "select orderId,orderData.customerId from Order" but I am not sure how to get the summation of all the prices and units.

What should be the best practice to get this done using apache spark?

Comment: cant we do like DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("/path/to/file").toDF();
    df.registerTempTable("df");
    df.printSchema(); and after that perform aggregates through sql ?

Comment: Through SQL I can get hold of individual elements but not sure about orders.items, how can I run aggregates on this? I think it will come as a json value only, please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: you can have a look through [this](http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.in/2015/06/reading-json-data-in-spark-dataframes.html) & [nested json] (http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.in/2016/05/reading-json-nested-array-in-spark.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ram, will try this out. This definitely looks to work.

Comment: ya another link I gave if it works well pls post the answer with your relevant use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> doc = {"orderData": {"orders": [{"items": [{"quantity": 1, "price": 315}, {"quantity": 2, "price": 300}], "itemCount": 2}], "customerId": 123}, "orderId": 1}
>>> df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize([doc]))
>>> df.select("orderId", "orderData.customerId", explode("orderData.orders").alias("order")) \
... .withColumn("item", explode("order.items")) \
... .groupBy("orderId", "customerId") \
... .agg(sum("item.quantity"), sum(col("item.quantity") * col("item.price")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the working logic, i will try to map it in java and post it here for others.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are looking for a java solution of the above, please follow:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();

    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(spark);

    Dataset<Row> orders = sqlContext.read().json("order.json");
    Dataset<Row> newOrders = orders.select(
            col("orderId"),
            col("orderData.customerId"),
            explode(col("orderData.orders")).alias("order"))
            .withColumn("item",explode(col("order.items")))
            .groupBy(col("orderId"),col("customerId"))
            .agg(sum(col("item.quantity")),sum(col("item.price")));
    newOrders.show();
```